# Getting Concurrent Modifiraction Exception. Where is the prob.lem? (code)

Tags: java, swing, concurrentmodification

Im writing a simple game in Java. Here is main code:

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private Player player = new Player(100, 100, 3, 3);
    private Point2D targetPoint = new Point2D.Float(130, 350); //Pos on begin
    private ArrayList<Beam> beams = new ArrayList<Beam>();

    public MainPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionHandler());
        //Add shortcuts
        makeShortcut("player.BM1", "F1", new SetBeamModeAction(1));
        makeShortcut("player.BM2", "F2", new SetBeamModeAction(2));

        //Start threads
        Thread t = new Thread(new PlayerMoveRunnable());
        t.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new PlayerShootRunnable());
        t2.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 400);
        //Draw player
        g2.drawImage(player.getImage(), (int)player.getX(), (int)player.getY(), null);
        //Draw beams
        for (Beam beam : beams) {
            g2.drawImage(beam.getImage(), (int)beam.getX(), (int)beam.getY(), null);
        }
    }

    //Thread running all the time
    private class PlayerMoveRunnable implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    player.moveToPoint(targetPoint);
                    repaint();
                    Thread.sleep(15);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //Thread working all the time
    private class PlayerShootRunnable implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    //Choose which beam to shoot (depends on set mode)
                    Thread t;
                    switch (player.getBeamMode()) {
                        case 1:
                            t = new Thread(new BeamMoveRunnable(new Beam1(player.getX()+18, player.getY(), 0, -15)));
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            t = new Thread(new BeamMoveRunnable(new Beam2(player.getX()+18, player.getY(), 0, -30)));
                            break;
                        default:
                            t = null;
                            break;
                    }
                    t.start();
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class BeamMoveRunnable implements Runnable {
        private Beam beam;

        public BeamMoveRunnable(Beam beam) {
            this.beam = beam;
        }

        public void run() {
            Beam beam = this.beam;
            beams.add(beam);
            try {
                while (true) {
                    if (beam.getY() <= 0) {
                        beams.remove(beam);
                        break;
                    }
                    beam.move();
                    repaint();
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**[its not whole code. I cut few lines which for sure arent causing problem]**

Im getting such error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:819)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:791)
    at spacecommander.MainPanel.paintComponent(MainPanel.java:53)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
```

and so on...

Where lies the problem? I know what ConcurrentModificationException means but I dont know where can be the problem here.. Maybe I should make some synchronization. If yes please show where

Comment: btw, your PlayerShootRunnable loops forever.  Every 200 msec, it creates a new BeamMoveRunnable thread, which also runs forever.  You're creating 5 new threads every second, and none of them ever exit.

Comment: When any beam gets to 0 or bigger position loop breaks so thread ends.

Comment: yes, fair point.  sorry, I missed that.  Still seems like substantial thread churn, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the list of beams in another thread e.g. `BeamMoveRunnable` while you are iterating over the collection.

Creating a thread per object is pretty wasteful and difficult to manage.

I suggest you have a one thread which periodically calls a method on each beam to move.  I suggest you not add or remove the beams while they are being drawn so you won't have to synchronize access to the collection.

Comment: Ok so I will change it and make one thread which would move every beam. But I think it wont help anyway because even then there is possiblity that thread will loop over collection and remove one element while paint method  will try to paint it.. So how to prevent it?

Comment: Which is why I said, don't remove any elements. You can draw only the elements visible in the `paintComponent` instead of removing them.

Comment: But wouldnt it affect performance of application? Or wouldnt throw any exception like stack overflow etc? New beam is added automaticaly every 200ms so after few minutes of game there would be many of them.

Comment: I see, you have a shotting game.  In that case you will need to maintain a collection.  I would suggest you either use the Event Thread to move the beams, or your beam updating thread gives the GUI Thread a copy of the collection, or you synchronize the collection both when iterating and when updating (which is not as good are using just the Event thread I suspect)

Comment: What I made is making a copy of arrayList before drawing. Looks it works so thanks for help.

Comment: You have to take a copy when it is modifed. If you take a copy just before drawing you reduce the chance of a CME but it can still happen. (A copy uses an Iterator too)

Comment: An alternative is to use a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`  This will automatically do the copy for you as required and doesn't need to be synchronized.

Comment: Yeah last solution is the best. I used it and doesnt see any problem (with removing as well). Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Before iterating the beams in `paintComponent` create a copy of the collection and use the copy to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the array list `beams` in the thread `BeamMoveRunnable` (the thread which wraps this `Runnable` object) simultaneously with iterating it in the method `paintComponent`. This is the cause for the exception.